# call bpel process in android

Tags: android, wsdl, bpel

I have one BPEL process.  And I want to call it in android. But I am not able to understand of wsdl url, namespace and method name.  Because I know that error is get because of that. I am send wsdl file and xsd file.

My BPEL process wsdl file is:

```
    <definitions name="HelloWorld" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld" schemaLocation="HelloWorld.xsd"/>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="HelloWorldRequestMessage">
        <part name="payload" element="tns:HelloWorldProcessRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="HelloWorldResponseMessage">
        <part name="payload" element="tns:HelloWorldProcessResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="HelloWorld">
        <operation name="process">
            <input message="tns:HelloWorldRequestMessage"/>
            <output message="tns:HelloWorldResponseMessage"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="HelloWorldBinding" type="tns:HelloWorld">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="process">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="process"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="HelloWorld">
        <port name="HelloWorldPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.sample.com/orabpel/default/HelloWorld/1.0"/>
        </port>
    </service>
  <plnk:partnerLinkType name="HelloWorld">
    <plnk:role name="HelloWorldProvider">
      <plnk:portType name="tns:HelloWorld"/>
    </plnk:role>
  </plnk:partnerLinkType>
</definitions>
```

My xsd file is:

```
    <schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="HelloWorldProcessRequest">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="input" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
    <element name="HelloWorldProcessResponse">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="result" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

My android code is:

```
    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

    import android.R.string;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    public class SOAP_WebService extends Activity
    {
         private final String NAMESPACE = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld";
         private final String URL = "http://http://www.sample.com/orabpel/default/HelloWorld/1.0";
         private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld/process";
         private final String METHOD_NAME = "process";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.soap_webservice);

         Button btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
         btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                callWebservice();
            }
        });
    }
    public void callWebservice()
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
        weightProp.setName("input");
        weightProp.setValue("sample");
        weightProp.setType(string.class);
        request.addProperty(weightProp);



        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = false;
        envelope.bodyOut = request;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try 
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            Log.i("myApp", response.toString());

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Exception Generated", ""+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

I got following error:

```
 01-06 00:32:39.572: W/System.err(317): SoapFault - faultcode: 'null:HelloWorld' faultstring: 'Cannot figure out operation name. Bad SOAPAction or wsa:Action.' faultactor: 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/HelloWorld/process' detail: null 01-06
 00:32:39.572: W/System.err(317): at    org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:141)
 01-06 00:32:39.572: W/System.err(317): at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140) 01-06
 00:32:39.582: W/System.err(317): at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100) 01-06
 00:32:39.582: W/System.err(317): at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:197)
 01-06 00:32:39.582: W/System.err(317): at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
 01-06 00:32:39.582: W/System.err(317): at com.mehul.Web_Service.SOAP_WebService.callWebservice(SOAP_WebService.java:69)
 01-06 00:32:39.582: W/System.err(317): at com.mehul.Web_Service.SOAP_WebService$1.onClick(SOAP_WebService.java:40)
 01-06 00:32:39.582: W/System.err(317): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 01-06 00:32:39.582:
 W/System.err(317): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 01-06 00:32:39.582:
 W/System.err(317): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 01-06
 00:32:39.582: W/System.err(317): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-06
 00:32:39.592: W/System.err(317): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-06 00:32:39.592:
 W/System.err(317): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 01-06
 00:32:39.592: W/System.err(317): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-06
 00:32:39.592: W/System.err(317): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 01-06 00:32:39.592:
 W/System.err(317): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 01-06 00:32:39.592: W/System.err(317): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 01-06
 00:32:39.592: W/System.err(317): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-06 00:32:39.592: D/Exception Generated(317): Cannot figure out operation name. Bad
 SOAPAction or wsa:Action.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value given for the soapAction in the above java code is incorrect. It should be
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "process";

Please check the soapAction in the wsdl.